# Photo Multiplier Tube Usage

Tags: photons, measurements

How is it determined that a PMT measures only one photon ?
By the energy that one photon is supposed to have ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately PMTs don't do that, at least not cleanly. One of the crucial performance characteristics for photon counting is the peak-to-valley ratio of the PMT, which you get by measuring a pulse-height distribution. PMTs produce dark noise, which means they indicate "photons" that aren't there and they can't cleanly tell the difference between one and two (or more) photons that have been detected at the same time. One has to find ways to work around that in experiments which use PMTs. If you want to know more, I would suggest you read Hamamatsu's PMT handbook. It contains a lot of technical information about PMTs (and, yes, PMTs are primarily a technology, not a physical system, so the important information is on the engineering side, unless, of course, you decide to go into the PMT manufacturing business yourself): http://www.hamamatsu.com/us/en/support/lib/index.html?spsort=cz&spkey=pmt+handbook&screen=lib&spcats=Technical+Information. See also www2.pv.infn.it/~debari/doc/Flyckt_Marmonier.pdf, physics111.lib.berkeley.edu/Physics111/Equipment_Manuals/RCA_PMT.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

The work function of the photocathode is such that it can eject no more than one electron for each photon.  Well, it's possible that very energetic photons can eject two, but that process is rare, and can be suppressed with filters.  So that's the sense that it's said that PMTs detect single photons.

But only 30% to 70% of photons in the proper energy range actually emit electrons.  The energy of the photons that don't eject photons go to other channels, most likely ending up as thermal energy.

And as @CuriousOne points out, electrons can be emitted by thermal energy without the need of a photon.  Furthermore, electrons can be emitted from the first dynode without need of a primary electron.   And what's more, the number of secondary electrons emitted at each dynode is not fixed, so there ends up being a rather wide distribution of electron energies once they reach the anode.  The consequence of all that is the anode current caused by one incident photon varies significantly from photon to photon, so it's not always easy to distinguish a current pulse from a noise pulse. You can't say with absolute certainty that what you've detected is a photon.

Comment: I'm a retired BSEE wanting to do experiments. Had read Feynmann's 4% reflection and instead of 8% you get 0% to 16% depending on thickness and wondered what happens with just one photon.

Comment: @JohnnyM I don't quite understand what you are saying ... what do you mean to say by those percentages?  How do they relate to your question about one photon?

Comment: Feynmann's book QED he talks about light incident to glass reflects 4% and it would of been thought that the back side of the glass would contribute another 4% for a total of 8% of the light would be reflected. Yet it was found that the light reflected varied from 0% to 16% depending upon the thickness of the glass. Seems like experiments with one photonn would be interesting.